# Rewriting from http to https and retain URL

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

i need to create a rewrite rule to redirect my page from 
`http://example.com` to `https://example.com`.

But in the case that the client opened the page with any GET parameter, it should remain the same without any redirecting.  For example:

- `http://example.com/index.php` should redirect to `https://example.com/index.php`
- `http://example.com/index.php?param1=val1` should not redirect.

Comment: And the webserver is ? {apache|nginx|lighttpd|IIS|...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([^?]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```